# Menu item hyperlink does not work

Tags: html

First post here with something that is probably easy but escapes me.
On this site, which I wrote from scratch, the contact link does not jump to the div class "contact".
The site is www.whatyousaycounts.com.  I am also open to any other feedback for improvements that you see are needed.

Comment: Can you also add the code for the link and the target div please?

Comment: Please read about how to ask questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlinks can only refer to ids, you are trying to refer to a class though. Classes can be used several times, therefore, your link can't target anything.

All you have to do is add the id="contact" to your div and it will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your other sections have something like:

```
<div class="videos" id="videos">
```

Whereas your Contact section is:

```
<div class="contact">
```

It needs the `id` to be set as well.

Comment: Awesome!   New it was something easy.